# Is there any extension to import csv OR xls data into tt_address in typo3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am using typo3 6.2, is there any backend extension available  to import csv OR xls data into tt_address in typo3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on a 6.2 compatibility upgrade of EXT:rs_userimp. You can find the current (working) state over at [Github](https://github.com/visol/ext-rs_userimp).

Comment: Thanks Lorenz. When we will get the updated version?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not the official maintainer of the extension. I created to fork for my own use so everyone can use it, but I don't know if I will be able to release it.